# Webflux Webclient: Is there a way to use lets say 2 different filter chains on a webclient?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Lets assume that I need to post certain data and the headers that needs to be added to my current webclient request method is conditional(Depends on some header values i.e. if a certain header is present in the upstream call then I need to add some more headers in my current request else the happy story). Any idea, how can we configure this?

Assuming **request** is my incoming call from upstream. Current weblclient configuration

```
                   webClient.post()
                            .uri(request.destination())
                            .header(// Some header value here)
                            .header(// Some header value here)
                            .headers(// More headers from upstream)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request.data()))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(//);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the point is how to chain several filters.

If you look at the source code of Webclient, you can see the following:

```java
  public WebClient.Builder filter(ExchangeFilterFunction filter) {
    Assert.notNull(filter, "ExchangeFilterFunction must not be null");
    this.initFilters().add(filter);
    return this;
  }

  public WebClient.Builder filters(Consumer<List<ExchangeFilterFunction>> filtersConsumer) {
    filtersConsumer.accept(this.initFilters());
    return this;
  }

  private List<ExchangeFilterFunction> initFilters() {
    if (this.filters == null) {
      this.filters = new ArrayList();
    }

    return this.filters;
  }
```

You can add different filters which not related together directly, just there are contained in a list. When you send a request, it will be run it is affected the chain orders list position (or use *andThen* method). *Note that this is a lambda.*

```java
  public WebClient build() {
    ClientHttpConnector connectorToUse = this.connector != null ? this.connector : this.initConnector();
    ExchangeFunction exchange = this.exchangeFunction == null ? ExchangeFunctions.create(connectorToUse, this.initExchangeStrategies()) : this.exchangeFunction;

    
    ExchangeFunction filteredExchange = this.filters != null ? (ExchangeFunction)this.filters.stream().reduce(ExchangeFilterFunction::andThen).map((filter) -> {
      return filter.apply(exchange); // <-- Here. 
    }).orElse(exchange) : exchange;
 
    HttpHeaders defaultHeaders = this.copyDefaultHeaders();
    MultiValueMap<String, String> defaultCookies = this.copyDefaultCookies();
    return new DefaultWebClient(filteredExchange, this.initUriBuilderFactory(), defaultHeaders, defaultCookies, this.defaultRequest, new DefaultWebClientBuilder(this));
  }
```